# Recursive Feature Elimination on Keras Models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, feature-selection

I want to apply Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) on a model that is built using Keras models and layers. When I run:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
## building Keras model ... #
rfe = RFE(model, 3)
rfe = rfe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot clone object '<keras.models.Sequential object at 0x7f1ab93eb510>' (type <class 'keras.models.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

I tried to clone my Keras model by `clone_model(model)`, but it did not help.
Do I have to use sklearn estimator to be able to use RFE?

Comment: Yes. You need to use scikit compliant classes to use the RFE, GridSearch or any other scikit-learn methods like cross_val_score etc. The keras has one wrapper to make a Sequential model to scikit usable, which can be [found here](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/)

Comment: @VivekKumar, thanks for providing the link. I will read it.